# writing escape sequence in C using hex, dec, and oct values?

Tags: c, types, escaping, sequence

Can someone explain this question to me? I don't understand how the book arrived at its values or how one would arrive at the answer.

Here is the question:

> Suppose that `ch` is a type `char` variable. Show how to assign the carriage-return character to `ch` by using an escape sequence, a decimal value, an octal character constant, and a hex character constant. (Assume ASCII code values.)

Here is the answer:

> Assigning the carriage-return character to `ch` by using:
>
> a) escape sequence:           `ch='\r';`
> b) decimal value:         `ch=13;`
> c) an octal character constant:   `ch='\015';`
> d) a hex character constant:  `ch='\xd';`

I understand the answer to part a, but am completely lost for parts b, c, and d.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers represent characters using character encondings, such as ascii, utf-8, utf-16, iso-8859 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), as well as others.  The carriage return character was used by early computers as a printer instruction to return the printhead to the leftmost position.  And the linefeed character was used to index the paper to a new line (thus why DOS uses CRLF for lines, it worked better with dot matrix printers).  Anyway the CR character is stored internally as a numeric value in either a single 8-bit byte/octet or a 16-bit pair of two bytes/octets, depending upon your language.

The common ascii characterset is found here:  http://www.asciitable.com/ and you can find that CR, '\r', 13, 0xD, et al are different representations for the same value.

Strings are just sequences of characters stored either as an array of characters with a marker at the end (terminator), or stored with a count of the current string length.

Comment: Ohhhh! That makes sense now! I thought I had to find the ascii code for 'r' so I would find the number part of '\#'. Now I see that "\r" is the whole number, the slash is included to make one character with it's own separate ascii code!  Thank you very much for your help! I once was lost... now I am found :)

Answer (score 3):

From wiki:

> Computers and communication equipment represent characters using a
>   character encoding that assigns each character to something — an
>   integer quantity represented by a sequence of bits, typically — that
>   can be stored or transmitted through a network. Two examples of usual
>   encodings are ASCII and the UTF-8 encoding for Unicode.

For your question b,c,d - all values are 13 (in decimal). Run this code to understand what's happening:

```
char ch1='\r';
printf("Ascii value of carriage return is %d", ch1);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to explaining answers b-d.

1. You need to know that the ASCII code point for 'carriage return' or CR (also known as <kbd>Control-M</kbd>) is 13.  You can find that out from various sources.  It might not be obvious that the [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts) standard is one of those places (but it is) and U+000D is CARRIAGE RETURN (CR).  Unicode code points U+0000..U+007F are identical to ASCII; Unicode code points U+0000..U+00FF are identical to ISO 8859-1 (Latin 1).
2. You need to know that C can use decimal numbers, or octal or hexadecimal escapes when assigning to characters.  Notations such as `'\15'` or `'\015'` are octal character constants, and octal 15 is decimal 13.  Notations such as `'\xD'` or `'\x0D'` (or, indeed, `'\x0000000000000D'` and all stops *en route*) are hexedecimal constants and hex D is also decimal 13.  (Note that octal escapes are limited to 1-3 digits, but hex escapes are not so limited, but values larger than `'\xFF'` typically have implementation defined representations.)